# Windows explorer does not open duplicate folders

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

When I try to double click a folder on Desktop that is already open, windows just brings up the window that was already open. However, I actually want a duplicate of that window.

I want bringing up a duplicate window to be the default behavior. Any way to make this happen?

Comment: In Windows File Explorer, try File, Open New Window. Works for me.

Comment: I don't want a work around, I want it to be the default behavior to bring up a new window when I double click a folder on the Desktop even if it is already open.

Comment: Short of hacking your system, double click will not open a new Window.

Comment: It does open a new window when you double click a folder on desktop, so long as it is not already open.

Comment: I understand that part. When the folder is already open, double click will not open it. That is what I meant and I should have been more clear.

Comment: On my Windows 10 version 21H1 this works exactly as you demand. Strange why it doesn't for you. What's your Windows version? Try: Explorer > View pane > Options > View pane, click Reset Folders.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one solution, not sure if it will work while on the Desktop, but it will work in File Explorer... Open File Explorer and click the **View** tab, then on then under **Options** click **Change Folder and View Options** and select under Browser Folders: **Open each folder in its own window**
[image]

Comment: On my Windows 10 version 21H1 this works exactly as as the poster demands, no matter what your option is set to.

Comment: This opens literally everything in a new window. I only want this to happen when I click on a folder on the desktop.

Comment: I'm not sure of a way of achieving that, other than manually opening the folder in a new window. Is there a specific reason you need it to work with double-click?

Comment: The primary reason this really annoys me is, when using virtual desktop and I double click an existing window, it whisks me away to a different desktop just to not open it in a new window. 

Some other people complaining about this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-virtual-desktop-automatic-switching/2dcaed5c-2257-45e4-8ff7-18edab1369b2

Comment: @berala - You failed to mention you were using virtual desktop in your question.

Comment: This behavior happens virtual desktop or not. It is just more annoying when it happens across virtual desktops. Ideally it shouldnt happen in either case.